# Someone got convert coverage in new version xcode12 - SonarQube

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sonarqube

I'm trying to perform the conversion for SonarQube to interpret coverage and I get this error:

```
Error: Error Domain=XCCovErrorDomain Code=0 "Failed to load result bundle" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load result bundle, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdaa840a8d0 {Error Domain=IDEFoundation.ResultBundleError Code=0 "This version of Xcode does not support opening result bundles created with versions of Xcode and xcodebuild using the v1 API."}}
The operation couldn’t be completed. (cococoLibrary.Bash.Error error 0.)
```

Comment: I have no experience with SonarQube but the error looks pretty clear to me. You probably have two options. A) Go back to the previous version of Xcode you were using. B) Get a new version of the API (if there is one) which will probably support opening previous results.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version. There is a new version: 8.5 released this month.

Comment: @LeoDabus Using the latest version of xcode was a definition of the architecture team, we need to solve what previously worked in the version of xcode11. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update slather to version 2.5 and also generate coverage in the sonarqube generic mode. Follow the steps for successful reproduction:

```
Build
xcodebuild -workspace 'YourProject.xcworkspace' -scheme DEV -derivedDataPath Build/ -enableCodeCoverage YES clean build test CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=14.0'

Slather generate sonarqube generic xml
slather coverage --jenkins --sonarqube-xml --build-directory ./Build --output-directory ./sonar-reports --scheme DEV --workspace YourProject.xcworkspace

Run analise Sonarqube
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.coverageReportPaths=./sonar-reports/sonarqube-generic-coverage.xml -Dproject.settings=sonar-project.properties -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This page gives steps to generate code coverage for various Xcode versions. there are primarily 3 steps as shown in the description.

1. Build project
2. Create code coverage report
3. Import code coverage report

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/swift-coverage

This is a popular page to integrate CI with Sonar as well, its from SonarSource.